# Python: how to compute min, max, median, 1st and 3rd quartiles from a dict of lists?

Tags: python, dictionary, max, min

Let's say I have a dict of lists like this:

`mydict={10:[],20:[],30:[],40:[],50:[1],60:[],70:[1],80:[7, 2, 7, 2, 2, 7, 2],90:[5, 2, 2, 6, 2, 3, 1, 2, 1, 2],...}`

I want to compute: min, max, median, 1st and 3rd quartiles for each list in the dict. I tried `min` and `max` first, like this:

`mins_mydict={k:min(v) for k,v in mydict.items()}`

`maxes_mydict={k:max(v) for k,v in mydict.items()}`

but I get this error: `ValueError: min() arg is an empty sequence`. Same for `max`. Is it because some of my lists are empty?

How can I create an exception that checks if `len(list)=0`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
In [4]: mydict={10:[],20:[],30:[],40:[],50:[1],60:[],70:[1],80:[7, 2, 7, 2, 2, 7, 2],90:[5, 2, 2, 6, 2, 3, 1, 2, 1, 2]}

In [5]: import pandas as pd

In [6]: df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dict([ (k, pd.Series(v)) for k,v in mydict.items() ]))

In [7]: print(df.min())
10    NaN
20    NaN
30    NaN
40    NaN
50    1.0
60    NaN
70    1.0
80    2.0
90    1.0
dtype: float64

In [8]: df.max()
Out[8]: 
10    NaN
20    NaN
30    NaN
40    NaN
50    1.0
60    NaN
70    1.0
80    7.0
90    6.0
dtype: float64

In [9]: df.median()
Out[9]: 
10    NaN
20    NaN
30    NaN
40    NaN
50    1.0
60    NaN
70    1.0
80    2.0
90    2.0
dtype: float64

In [10]: df.quantile([.1, .3])
Out[10]: 
     10  20  30  40   50  60   70   80   90
0.1 NaN NaN NaN NaN  1.0 NaN  1.0  2.0  1.0
0.3 NaN NaN NaN NaN  1.0 NaN  1.0  2.0  2.0
```

Answer (score 7):

You can assign a default value for min, max. So, for empty list you will be notified.

```
>>> min([] or [-1])
-1
```

In your case

```
>>> {k:min(v or [-1]) for k,v in mydict.items()}
{70: 1, 40: -1, 10: -1, 80: 2, 50: 1, 20: -1, 90: 1, 60: -1, 30: -1}
>>> {k:max(v or ["empty list"]) for k,v in mydict.items()}
{70: 1, 40: 'empty list', 10: 'empty list', 80: 7, 50: 1, 20: 'empty list', 90: 6, 60: 'empty list', 30: 'empty list'}
```

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively to qmaruf's answer you can use a conditional inside your list comprehension in the following way:

```
mins_mydict={k:min(v) if (len(v) > 0) else 0 for k,v in mydict.items()}
```

Answer (score 1):

You got error because you applying min and max method on empty list.

```
>>> min([])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: min() arg is an empty sequence
```

your dictionary contains some key with empty list as values.

Comment: Exactly, this is my situation. It has to be like that.

Answer (score -1):

For a rapid look at your dataframe's count, mean, max, min, standard deviation and quartiles you can use `df.describe()`